# Can the LogicalOperationStack property ever be null?

Tags: c#, .net, trace

Can the System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.LogicalOperationStack property ever be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean `System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.LogicalOperationStack`.  No, it won't be null.  If the `CallContext` doesn't have an existing stack, for whatever reasons, a new stack will be allocated within the getter.